# Slow iteration in displaytag on 70000 or more records

Tags: java, struts2, export, displaytag

I am using `displayTag` for tabular view in my reports . It works fine up to 60K records but when the data exceeds 70K or more it took some time to display . Is there any limit for data in `displayTag` and same issue in `export` option why so much delay on heavy data.

My table has 30 columns and 70k+ rows

**Code**

```
<display:table id="listDisplay1" list="showLeadList" name="showLeadList" export="${session['Lead Status Report'][4]}" requestURI="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" pagesize="50">
            <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="false" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="false" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.excel" value="false" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.[mymedia].filename" value="LeadStatus_details${currentDateTime}.xlsx" />
            <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" /> 
            <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="LeadStatus_details${currentDateTime}.pdf"/>
            <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" /> 
            <display:column property="sno" title="S.No." media="html excel"></display:column>
            <s:iterator var="DisplayMap" value="#attr.listDisplay1.columnMap" >
                <display:column  title="${DisplayMap.key}" value="${DisplayMap.value}" />
            </s:iterator>
        </display:table>
```

I am using `version(2.3.15)` of Struts2.

**2nd Question** Is it true that `displayTag` use `get` method for `export`? if yes then how can we modify it to `post` method?

Comment: Have you EVER seen a website showing you dozens of thousands of rows in a single page ? WHO on earth wanna scroll 70.000 rows in a table ? Pagination anyone ???? :| If the only purpose of your table is the export functionality, then bypass the table, and generate directly a .csv (manually) or .xls (with POI or JXL) file.

Comment: That is good to know that display tag can handle 60k rows w/o problems. :D

Comment: @AndreaLigios i already use the pagination just see the above code and the limit is 50 record per page

Comment: @AleksandrM yeahh it's good that display tag work on 60k records but i want better than that. So give any suggestions to improve the output

Comment: Then it means that it loads 70000 records every time, for just showing you 50 of them. A bit inefficient, isn't it ? :| I strongly suggest you to switch to jqGrid (or eventually to a self made grid) and load only 50 records per request, by filtering the data directly in the query, not after having loaded it

Comment: @AndreaLigios i use display tag to give easy export option. At the time of export it will export all the data not just 50.

Comment: Exactly (what Andrea said). If you need to use display tag then you can try with external paging. But you are better off doing paging yourself and using some js library for datagrid.

Comment: @AleksandrM why external paging? How this will improve the output of display tag

Comment: See http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/tut_externalSortAndPage.html.

Comment: @amitbhardwaj Because then displaytag doesn't have to handle the paging.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only problem I ever had with displayTag!
it load whole table in memory for each time you use it! even if you change the page!

you have to change Query in source code and add some boundaries!